# Unable to fetch CPU/GPU fans data in Ubuntu

Tags: fan, fancontrol, msi

I have both Windows10 as well Ubuntu20.04 installed on my machine, MSI GV62 7RD. The ***MSI DragonCenter*** application on Windows clearly displays the RPMs of both the fans in real-time. However, I have not been able to fetch fans information in Ubuntu.

Already tried `lm-sensors` but no information about fan speed!

I wish to display the CPU fan RPMs in my "Vitals" gnome extension.

It would be really great if someone could guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After running `sudo sensors-detect` you should have output something like:

```
To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
#chip drivers
coretemp
nct6775
#----cut here----
```

take the info from the output and enter in terminal

```
sudo modprobe nct6775 coretemp
```

replacing nct6775 & coretemp with your module names from the output of sensors-detect (Although I suspect you will have the same values).

[lm-sensors trick and tips](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/advanced-lm-sensors-tips-and-tricks-linux-0/)